# SQL Server Replication issue- sp_MS... stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-replication

I'm setting up a transactional replication.

When I do it manually and setup `sp_MSins_..` and other 2 stored procedures in the article - it works ok - creates those stored procedures on the Subscriber.

But when I set this up through the script I can't figure out the `@schema_option`.

I tried 0x01, and 0x02 separately, but they don't create the stored procedures on the Subscriber when running `sp_addarticle`, and even when I rebuild the whole publication.

What my @schema_option in my script should be?

I want the stored procedures created on the subscriber, and regenerated when that article table schema changes.

Comment: You need to read up on bitwise operations...

Comment: Ok, Can you please paste here an example of what I will put in the @schema_option argument.

Comment: I tell you what - best thing to do is use the wizards to generate the article properties by selecting all the options you want, then script out the article.  That will be the fastest way to get what you want, without dinking around with bitwise.